# React Native ,why can't I align picker item to right in android platform?

Tags: react-native

I tried to find the solution for ages , but it's still none working! Below is how I wrote:

```
<View style = {[ {flex: 0.7} ]}>
    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedGender}
        onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this, 'selectedGender')}
        >
        <Item label="Please select gender" value=""/>  
        <Item label="Male" value="M" /> 
        <Item label="Female" value="F" />
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change the style of the picker items on Android, you have to change native code.

You'll have to add your style in `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`.

**To change the picker container**

Here I set, the background to `null` so there is not the down arrow on the left.

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

**To change the selected item style**

Here I set the items to be centered, the color font to be dark gray and the font size to 16.

```
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#373737</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

**To change the drapdown items**

Just as, the selected item, I want the dropdown items to have the same style.

```
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#373737</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

**Finally**

Once, you have set your styles for every element of the picker. You have to add the style to the general App theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: But how about config picker to align different way in different page?

Comment: Hm, as this solution changes the style for every Picker in your app, I guess you should have to implement different pickers in the native side and expose them to React Native. If you only want to change the `align` property, you could expose a basic Picker and add an attribute `align`, so you can define it in the React Native side. I don't know if there is another solution but that's all I can say :/

Comment: Thank for your solution but I just back from my holiday! Anyway I'm new with react native and android so could you give me some guide to expose the basic picker and add an attribute align and also how to define in react-native side?Hope , you don't mind to share ,thank ahead

Comment: Thank you so much. I research a lot and try so many different code to solve problem through react-native code only but didn't success so finally use this code still question in mind what about ios right align drop down?

Comment: @ElFreddy, how can i change the text Align,Thanks?